# Nested methods vs "piped" methods, which is better?

Tags: java

Since uni, I've programming in Java for 3 years, although I am not fully dedicated to this language, I have spent quite some time in it, nevertheless. I understand both ways, just curious which style do you prefer.

Please focus at the main method - that's the section I concern the most.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.println(getAgent().getAgentName());
    }

    private static Agent getAgent()
    {
        return new Agent();
    }
}
class Agent
{
    private String getAgentName()
    {
        return "John Smith";
    }
}
```

I am pretty happy with nested method calls such like the following

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.println(getAgentName(getAgent()));
    }

    private static String getAgentName(Agent agent)
    {
        return agent.getName();
    }

    private static Agent getAgent()
    {
        return new Agent();
    }
}
class Agent
{
    public String getName()
    {
        return "John Smith";
    }
}
```

They have identical output I saw "John Smith" twice.

I wonder, if one way of doing this has better performance or other advantages over the other. Personally I prefer the latter, since for nested methods I can certainly tell which starts first, and which is after.

The above code is but a sample, The code that I am working with now is much more complicated, a bit like a maze... So switching between the two styles often blows my head in no time.

Comment: That's an ... *interesting* brace style...

Comment: @Greg : I am not aware of the brace style, will google for that now.

Comment: @Michael Mao: if you don't find anything, see "Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language", particularly section 6.4: http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConvTOC.doc.html

Comment: @Greg : oh you mean indent style, ahhh, I normally match the curly braces, but got wrong when I posted it here... Okay, done, much better now.

Comment: I couldn't find any reason to introduce extra-method in #2, so I wouldn't recommend using it. Besides, such style will make your code harder to refactor and maintain.

Comment: @incarnate : good point. put some extra method is no good at all.

Comment: The first style is preferable, just a minor suggestion. It would be better if you rename the method `getAgentName` to `getName` as the name of the class already indicates that it abstracts Agent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against the latter style, since it mixes data retrieval with "busines logic" (i.e. what to do with the data).
With the first approach you keep a high degree of freedom in what you want to do with the data, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
      System.out.println(getAgent().getAgentName());
      System.err.println(getAgent().getAgentName());
      someTextArea.append("The agent name is: " + getAgent().getAgentName());
      // etc
}
```

If you chose to do things this way at least name the functions with names that clearly describes what is done, e.g.

```
private static void getAgentNameAndPrintIt(Agent agent)
{
    System.out.println(agent.getName());
}
```

Comment: Good point! I see now, if I treat the getAgent() as a dummy object reference like "agent", then the getAgentName() is certainly a method belongs to this object. Quite the opposite to my style, but now that it is obviously better than the other, I will change my mind now.

Answer (score 2):

The first example you posted nicely separates different parts of the problem into different methods. The second example, in the `getAgentName` method, conflates both the call to `.getName()` and the decision where to output (`System.out.println`). I would probably prefer the first style, since that gives the caller the most flexibility to decide what to print where.

Comment: That's a good point indeed. Actually I sort of made things clear for everyone to focus on the point - the actual code was done by someone else and the API and sample code that I am looking at is so hard to read, that's why I got the question.

Comment: I changed the second code a bit, would the first style is still the better one now?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the first style, as it keeps the implementation details closer to the object that is responsible for them. The second style tends to create more "utility methods" taking objects to act upon, but which do not involve objects of the class they are in to execute their function.

Your test class does not need the knowledge of where the agent class defined its `getAgentName` method, introducing a `getAgentName()` method in the test class adds unnecessary complexity to your codebase, and future maintainers need to check the extra method when working with it.

On another note, the agent class is the context of the `getAgentName()` method, so I would simplify it into `getName()` as the context is clear in:

```
System.out.println(getAgent().getName());
```

Comment: Good point. I made those method names myself so I really should have made them better before asking even they are all "fake" :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you stick with what you believe is the simplest and clearest.  Don't make things more complicate than they need to me.  Don't add complexity which doesn't make things clearer.

“Perfection is achieved perfection not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away” – Antoine de Saint-Exupery

I would keep taking things away, until it either doesn't do the same thing, or you lose clarity.

Put another way; the following does the same thing, what would you add to make this clearer?

```
class Test{public static void main(String[]args){System.out.println("John Smith");}}
```

Thank you @Michael Mao.

Comment: That's a good point. The only thing I can move away in your code example is the very first "public"